# Order of execution for identical Active Record callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model with 5 `after_create` callbacks. Do these callbacks get executed top to bottom? If not, what is the order of execution?

I know the docs list a precedence for each callback method, but they don't say anything about the order in which multiple callbacks of the same type are executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, callbacks of the same type are being executed from top to bottom - you can easily check it by yourself without digging into ActiveRecord code or searching for any documentation, for example this way:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create -> { log(1) }
  after_create -> { log(2) }
  after_create -> { log(3) }

  private

  def log(s)
    File.open("/tmp/logger.txt", "a") { |f| f.puts s }
  end

end
```

Now if you create a `City` and inspect the file, output will always be

```
1
2
3
```